# How to put a Listview under the existing one Listview. Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

hello there i want to add another one listview on the same screen, how can i do that?

hello there i want to add another one listview on the same screen, how can i do that?

[image]

here is my code:

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('detailsPage'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title:new Center(child:new Text(utf8.decode(appController.userName.runes.toList()) + " " + utf8.decode(appController.userSurname.runes.toList()))),
                  subtitle:new Center(child:new Text('UserID: '+appController.userid.toString())),
                )
            ),
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title:new Center(child:new  Text(months[index])),
                subtitle:new Center(child:new Text("This month you have done "+appController.Totaleachlength[index].toString()+' charges')),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title:new Center(child:new  Text(appController.Totaleachlist[index].toStringAsFixed(3)+"€")),
                  subtitle:new Center(child:new Text("Total amount")),

                )
            ),
            ElevatedButton(child: Text('Download Bill pdf'),
                onPressed: ()  => ''),
            ListTile(
              title: new Center(child: new Text('Details of your charges'),),
            ),
          ],
          shrinkWrap: true,
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Why do you want add another ListView? just add your second ListView items in the bottom of your first ListView items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to divide your screen, you can use `Column`

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('detailsPage'),),
  body : Column(
  children: [
   Expanded(flex: 2 // you can customize as you need
     child: ListView()
   ),
   Expanded(flex: 3 // you can customize as you need
     child: ListView()
   ),
])
```

Comment: where my appbar will go?

Answer (score 1):

```
Column:(
    children: [
        ListView1(),
        ListView2(),
    ]
),
```

If each list didnt scroll, wrap your each one with [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) and if you like to listviews expand all height you can use [Expanded](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html&ved=2ahUKEwjc2fGDkID7AhUphv0HHQHmD4AQtwJ6BAgOEAE&usg=AOvVaw2HDGNQcr0H1FrW8H2i2ai3)

You can also add your another ListView at last child like

```
ListView:(
   children: [
      Card()
      ListView()
   ]
)
```

Comment: where my appbar will go?

Comment: This is for body and appBar will be the same place

Answer (score 0):

- You have to use `shrinkWrap` in your child ListView to extend the size in the screen
- dont forget to add `ClampingScrollPhysics` to scroll from parent pehavior

  class NestedListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const NestedListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  ```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
              20, (index) => Text('Parent List View Index $index')),
          ListView(
            ///  * [ClampingScrollPhysics], which provides the clamping overscroll behavior
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),

            ///  * [shrinkWrap], which provides the Max size of list in screen
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: List.generate(
                20, (index) => Text('List View ONE Index $index')),
          ),
          ListView(
            physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: List.generate(
                20, (index) => Text('List View Two Index $index')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  ```

  }

[image: Exapmle]